# alias maybe shouldn't be an alias?

Tags: linux, unix

I am pretty new to creating aliases and functions at bash so I want something really simple 
in a nutshell

```
alias edit='emacs 'argv[0]'&'
```

so I can do edit junk.txt

to edit it on the background,but not sure if I actually need to create a function for something like this. This is probably way too obvious for unix people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function, not an alias:

```
edit() {
    emacs "$@" &
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this alias as:

```
alias edit='emacs '
```

**Note a space** before quote that will let you pass arguments directly to emacs command and then you can call this alias as:

```
edit junk.txt
```

OR

```
edit foo.sh
```

Comment: and where does the background stuff happen?

Comment: @glglgl: I believe you can call `edit foo.sh&`. Didn't test it though

Comment: If the `&` was to be entered, a direct call to `emacs` would be the thing to do. But the OP wanted to get rid of typing the `&` every time...

Comment: The space is not necessary or useful. Given `alias edit=emacs`, typing `edit junk.txt` is equivalent to typing `emacs junk.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you're trying to do with an alias, at least not in bash.

Quoting the [bash document](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html):

> There is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text, as in csh. If arguments are needed, a shell function should be used (see Shell Functions).

An alias can only be used as the first word of a simple command. There's no way to expand `edit foo.txt` to `emacs foo.txt &`.

(csh (and tcsh) aliases are more powerful, but csh lacks functions -- and you're using bash anyway.)

Note that the name `argv`, which you used in the attempt in your question, doesn't mean anything in particular in bash. Arguments (to a script or to a function) are referred to as `$1`, `$2`, etc.; the complete list of arguments is `$*` or `$@`. But that doesn't apply to aliases. The bash document explains all this.

[glglgl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16219137/827263) is correct: use a function.